# Slim framework: POST always null issue

Tags: php, oauth, slim

I'm trying to develope an authentication REST service with Slim. 
Testing it with a GET request, everything is ok.
However, when I try to use something with POST, it seems that both

```
$app->request()->post()
```

and

```
$app->request()->getBody()
```

are always null.

I'm implementing the classic login() function as folllows:

```
$app->post('/login', 'login');

function login() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $response = array();    
    $post = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());    
    $response['post'] = $app->request()->post();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE email = :email AND password = :password";
    try {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("email", $post->email);
        $stmt->bindParam("password", $post->password);
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['name'] = $user['name'];
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['mesage'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    echoRespnse(200, $response);
}

function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);

    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

### application/json request

Set `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, send data in the body as JSON:

```
{
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2"
}
```

and read data using:

```
$response['post'] = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
```

### application/x-www-form-urlencoded request

Set `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, send data in the body as `key=value`:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

and read data using:

```
$response['post'] = $app->request()->post();
```